# Is there a JNI shared stubs implementation for x64?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

There was this library that made C function call mappings in JNI easy.  I think it was called shared stubs API or something like that, and it is described in the famous JNI book and used to be available for download from Oracle site.  I cannot find it anymore.  Does anyone know  where it is now?

Most importantly, there was an inline assembly section of the code for x86 architecture in this implementation.  I wonder if somebody has found an x64 analog of this code?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this old question I asked a while ago. True, JNA is the way to go and this is what I ended up using.

Regarding recommendation to avoid native calls, performance considerations are not the only ones in decisions to use native API. I find myself often integrating Java with legacy code written in C/C++, often third party libraries for which I do not have source code (and frankly neither do I care to have it). One can wrap these libraries into native method calls, but often times this is a lot of work. JNA helps here quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the JNA library https://github.com/twall/jna

You should remember that calling assembly from Java can easily be much slower than writing the same thing in Java (which is compiled to native assembly anyway)

This is only useful is very, very rare situations.

Comment: Never used JNA, but am using shared stubs in my software currently.  Just trying to migrate the project to 64 bit windows.  My life would be easier if I just could find dispatch_x64.c instead of adopting a completely different way of accessing native APIs.  This is where my question is coming from.

Comment: I am open to looking at JNA, but it seems like quite an investment of time.  I cannot believe there is no easier way to do what I want.  Maybe there is no, but it is still an interesting issue to investigate a bit further before giving up on it.

Comment: Generally, I try to write everything in Java and avoid native code.  Generally, anything you can write in C you can write in Java with almost the same performance.

Comment: JNA was originally based on the JNI shared stubs by Sheng Liang.  It has a lot more functionality than the original, and is actually a fair bit easier to use in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are referring to is this book: `http://192.9.162.55/docs/books/jni/download/jni.pdf` ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the book I am talking about. In chapter 9 of this book there is a large section on shared stubs. The implementation of this shared stubs API used to be available for download from the Oracle site from the same place as the book, but I am not finding it anymore. Also, the implementation of shared stubs was only available for 32 bit platforms.  There was a file there called dispatch_x86.c that contained a dispatch function written in inline assembly. I am looking for implementation of this dispatch function for x64 Windows and Linux. I do not think I want to write it myself.

Comment: OK, I just found out that inline assembly on x64 is not supported in Visual Studio. I wonder if anyone knows of a way to make shared stubs working on x64.